# How can I set inline css styles for an element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div I'm displaying a button image on. I'm displaying a sprite actually. I'd added an onlick attribute to the tag and it calls a function called ACFunction. I know how to set the style attribute with css properties using javascript but I need to set the style attribute with each one of these properties below except I will set them to have different values slightly and those values will allow for the image I want to be displayed when the button is clicked, to show up.

so right now, this is the current inline style for the button

```
style="width:74px; height:99px; background:url(images/icons.png) -0px -0px;"
```

Can I use:

```
 document.getElementById('id').style.
```

for each one of those properties? How would I set the `background:url` one?

Comment: $("#id").css({"width":"74px", "height":"99px","background":"url(images/icons.png) -0px -0px"});

Comment: Or without jQuery: `document.getElementById(id).style.cssText = 'width:74px; height:99px; background:url(images/icons.png) -0px -0px;'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$("#id").css({"width":"74px", "height":"99px",
              "background":"url(images/icons.png) -0px -0px"});
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you can use

```
document.getElementById('id').style.property = value;
```

also like this

```
    document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute(
   "style", "font-size: 100px; font-style: italic; color:#ff0000;");
```

even this

```
document.getElementById("myElement").style.cssText = cssString;
```

[Css String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FCSSStyleDeclaration)

in jquery

```
$("#idname" or ".classname").css("property":"value");
```

Answer (score 0):

**in jquery**

for single attribute setting

```
$("#idname").css("background":"desired setting");// for background setting
```

for multiple attribute

```
$("#idname").css({"width":"74px",
                  "height":"99px",
                   "background":"url(images/icons.png) -0px -0px"
                  });
```

reference **[css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `document.getElementById('id').style.` 
use background attribute like `background: url('');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
* Define all styles with the classname "myStyles".

* $("#id").addClass("myStyles");
```